# Accessing jquery variables to php

Tags: php, jquery, tags

I am using https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it fot tagging

now i want to pass those value(tags) to my php page  so that i could store in database so far

i am doing the simple `$tags = $_POST["myTags"];`

unfortunately i am getting error thar undefined myTags

here is my html code

```
                <tr>                        
                    <td>Tags</td>
                        <td><ul id="myTags"  class= "ulc" name = "myTags"></ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
```

please tell me what i am doing wrong ?

or my method is incorrect

or Tagit has another way to do this ?

Comment: do let me know if any clarification required

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass javascript variables to php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UL` is not a "form input element".
Use elements that require inputs from user such as `INPUT`,`SELECT`,`TEXTAREA`, etc. to submit values using traditional form submit.

Answer (score 1):

the jquery is client side and php is server side, you most post the data to the php,
use the jquery post function, learn here: [http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/)

Comment: yeah i know but it doesn't mean that you can not perform jquery tagging in simple form post

Comment: also you can define your post `data`  variable values with the any attributes of any elements